# jq output is empty when tag name does not exist

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, jq

When I run the jq command to parse a json document from the amazon cli I have the following problem.

I’m parsing through the IP address and a tag called "Enviroment". The enviroment tag in the instance does not exist therefore it does not throw me any result.

Here's an example of the relevant output returned by the AWS CLI

```
{
  "Reservations": [
    {
      "Instances": [
        {
          "PrivateIpAddress": "10.0.0.1",
          "Tags": [
            {
              "Key": "Name",
              "Value": "Balance-OTA-SS_a"
            },
            {
              "Key": "Environment",
              "Value": "alpha"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Instances": [
        {
          "PrivateIpAddress": "10.0.0.2",
          "Tags": [
            {
              "Key": "Name",
              "Value": "Balance-OTA-SS_a"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I’m running the following command

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=Balance-OTA-SS_a" | jq -c '.Reservations[].Instances[] | ({IP: .PrivateIpAddress, Ambiente: (.Tags[]|select(.Key=="Environment")|.Value)})'

## output
empty
```

How do I show the IP address in the output of the command even if the enviroment tag does not exist?

Regards,

Comment: Please review the [mcve] guidelines. Specifically, what result do you want if there are no matching tags?  Do you expect the "Ambiente" key to be present?

Comment: My English is not good, I have reformulated my question.

Comment: IMHO, a better example would be one that showed sample JSON data so one doesn't have to fetch aws ec2 data to answer the JQ question.

Comment: I've included example input in my answer, but please please include example input when asking jq questions based on the output from AWS commands, it's dreadfully inconvenient for others to acquire test data like this even if they _do_ have an AWS account, which many of the people who could otherwise answer the question don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume this input:

```
{
  "Reservations": [
    {
      "Instances": [
        {
          "PrivateIpAddress": "10.0.0.1",
          "Tags": [
            {
              "Key": "Name",
              "Value": "Balance-OTA-SS_a"
            },
            {
              "Key": "Environment",
              "Value": "alpha"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Instances": [
        {
          "PrivateIpAddress": "10.0.0.2",
          "Tags": [
            {
              "Key": "Name",
              "Value": "Balance-OTA-SS_a"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the format returned by describe-instances, but with all the irrelevant fields removed.

Note that tags is always a list of objects, each of which has a `Key` and a `Value`. This format is *perfect* for [`from_entries`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries), which can transform this list of tags into a convenient mapping object. Try this:

```
.Reservations[].Instances[] |
{
  IP: .PrivateIpAddress,
  Ambiente: (.Tags|from_entries.Environment)
}
```

```
{"IP":"10.0.0.1","Ambiente":"alpha"}
{"IP":"10.0.0.2","Ambiente":null}
```

---

That answers how to do it. But you probably want to understand why your approach didn't work.

```
.Reservations[].Instances[] |
{
  IP: .PrivateIpAddress,
  Ambiente: (.Tags[]|select(.Key=="Environment")|.Value)
}
```

The `.[]` filter you're using on the tags can return zero or multiple results. Similarly, the `select` filter can eliminate some or all items. When you apply this *inside* an object constructor (the expression from `{` to `}`), you're causing that whole object to be created a variable number of times. You need to be very careful where you use these filters, because often that's not what you want at all. Often you instead want to do one of the following:

- Wrap the expression that returns multiple results in an array constructor `[ ... ]`. That way instead of outputting the parent object potentially zero or multiple times, you output it once containing an array that potentially has zero or multiple items. E.g.

  ```
  [.Tags[]|select(.Key=="Environment")]
  ```
- Apply `map` to the array to keep it an array but process its contents, e.g.

  ```
  .Tags|map(select(.Key=="Environment"))
  ```
- Apply `first(expr)` to capture only the first value emitted by the expression. If the expression might emit zero items, you can use the comma operator to provide a default, e.g.

  ```
  first((.Tags[]|select(.Key=="Environment")),null)
  ```
- Apply some other array-level function, such as `from_entries`.

  ```
  .Tags|from_entries.Environment
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use an `if ... then ... else ... end` construct, or `//`. For example:

```
.Reservations[].Instances[]
| {IP: .PrivateIpAddress} + 
  ({Ambiente: (.Tags[]|select(.Key=="Environment")|.Value)}
   // null)
```

Comment: I need to show at least the IP address if the tag doesn’t exist, that way the output is still empty.